# Problem in removing a list of nan from Pandas dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, nan

I have a dataframe which has 4 columns- Name, Size, Text Extracted, Score.
The score column contains a list with nan in it
something like this

```
[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]
```

Here's how my dataframe looks like

```
Image Name  Image Dimensions    Text Extracted  score
SGAFIS2457_1_1.jpg  (1260, 1585, 3)         "[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]"
SGAFIS2457_1_2.jpg  (1235, 1595, 3)         "[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]"
SGAFIS2457_2_1.jpg  (1402, 1668, 3) FIS      GLOBAL SUSTAINABILITY REPORT TABLE OF CONTENTS INTRODUCTION SUSTAINABLE PLANET I  LETTER FROM OUR CHAIRMAN AND CEO      REDUCING ENVIRONMENTAL IMPACT    II  ABOUT FIS   III  REPORT HIGHLIGHTS    SUSTAINABLE GOVERNANCE IV  APPROACH TO SUSTAINABLE GROWTH   V  RESPONSE TO COVID        GOVERNANCE OVERSIGHT  STRUCTURE AND RESOURCES    SUSTAINABLE SOCIETIES RISK MANAGEMENT  OPERATIONAL RESILIENCY AND COMPLIANCE    EMPOWERING INDIVIDUALS AND MANAGING A SUSTAINABLY BUSINESSES IN THE DIGITAL ECONOMY    FOCUSED SUPPLY CHAIN    PROTECTING OUR CLIENTS AND THE FINANCIAL SYSTEM APPENDIX      ADVANCING THE WORKFORCE OF THE FUTURE       CONTENT INDEXES    FOSTERING INCLUSION   DIVERSITY    HELPING COMMUNITIES THRIVE    INTRODUCTION  0.384155154
/content/keras-retinanet/PDFs/KPI1/Cropped_images/KPI1_SGAFIS2457_7_1.jpg   (1105, 865, 3)  MATRIX OF MATERIAL TOPICS Local Communities Training and Education Diversity   Equal Opportunity Indirect Economic Impacts Ethics and Integrity Employment Data Privacy and Security Governance Customer Privacy Access to Economic Finance Performance   Procurement Indirect Energy Economic Impacts Practices Anti Corruption Business Continuity Anti Competitive Behavior Public Policy INCREASING IMPORTANCE INDUSTRY PERSPECTIVES SUSTAINABLE SUSTAINABLE SUSTAINABLE SOCIETIES PLANET GOVERNANCE EXTERNAL STAKEHOLDERS  PERSPECTIVES    0.352203667
SGAALDAR DH_44_1.jpg    (758, 1147, 3)  GRI         "[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]"
SGAALDAR DH_96_1.jpg    (1266, 2316, 3)     "[nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan
 nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan nan]"
```

For your reference I'm also attaching a screenshot of the it here [image: data frame of 4 columns where nan in a list is in 4th column]

I've tried multiple ways of removing the whole row where the nan in list is present but none of them worked so far. Here's a snippet of code which I tried would solve it but it did not work.

```
dfKPI = dfKPI[~dfKPI['score'].isin(garb)]
```

here garb is nothing but the list shared above.

I'm stuck on this problem for a good two days and have researched and tried out multiple things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the look of it, it seems that your score column has usually a numerical result, but sometimes has a `string` containing `"[nan nan nan ...]"` rather than a `list` of `nan`.

One simple way to clean this up (here assuming an original DataFrame called `df`) is:

```py
df_new = df.assign(score=pd.to_numeric(df['score'], errors='coerce'))
```

Optionally, you can drop all rows with `nan` (either resulting from the 'coerce' above, or originally `nan`):

```py
df_new = (
    df
    .assign(score=pd.to_numeric(df['score'], errors='coerce'))
    .dropna(subset='score')
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your immediate response, this worked perfectly as wanted..wonder how I missed testing it in this way, thanks for showing how it's done